# Django + Vue.js GET /ws HTTP/1.1 404 2292 error every second

Tags: django, vue.js

I am building a project with Vue.js on the front-end and Django on the back-end. I am using port 8000 for Django and port 8080 for Vue.js. Every time I route to something on the 8080 port, I get this error like this that gets printed out every second:

```
[01/Apr/2022 17:18:57] "GET /ws HTTP/1.1" 404 2292
Not Found: /ws
```

This is my vue.config.js:

```json
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '^/ws': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8000'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Here is the Django urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('favicon.ico', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('users.urls')),
    path('api/', include('leagues.urls')),
]
```

I can't figure out why this happens or how to fix it.

Comment: Are you using https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy?

It sounds like your Vue devserver maybe using https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/hot-reload.html and is making requests to django.

Comment: I have the proxy setup on the right port and hot reload is enabled. As long as I can find a way to not have the 404 errors to /ws show up, I believe I'll have my problem resolved @ThomasMatecki .

Comment: I use Vue2 + Django. It happen to me only when I use Firefox. On Chrome I don't get this  message.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution to a similar way as Thomas. It seems that the default behavior of setting a proxy in vue.config.js is to send a GET request to /ws. I had to change the /ws in Thomas's answer to /api since that is what the back-end uses for their routes, so I ended up with this:

```json
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '^/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8000'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your [proxy config](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy), you probably want something like this:

```
      '^/ws': {
          target: 'localhost:8080',
      },
```

... basically, don't proxy the `/ws` path, send those requests to the devserver. Or maybe there is a common prefix for your django endpoints you can use to qualify paths that should be proxied.

Comment: I didn't notice a difference. The issue is on the Django side and not the Vue side.